# Looking for the existence of a joint probability is equivalent to looking for the existence of a conditional probability?

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

I want to understand whether looking for the existence of a joint probability is equivalent to looking for the existence of a conditional probability.

Let $\mathcal{V}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, not finite. Let $\mathcal{Y}\equiv \{0,1\}$.

Fix a [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) on $\mathcal{Y}$ and denote it by $p:\mathcal{Y}\rightarrow [0,1]$. Fix a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)  on $\mathcal{V}$ and denote it by $g:\mathcal{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Fix a function $u: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Consider the following program: find a [mixed joint density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Mixed_case) $f: \mathcal{V}\times\mathcal{Y}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (1) \quad \int_{\mathcal{V}} f(v,y)dv=p(y)\quad && \text{ for each $y\in \mathcal{Y}$} & \quad \text{[the marginal of $f$ on $\mathcal{Y}$ is $p$]}\\
& (2) \quad  f(v,1)+f(v,0)=g(v)\quad  && \text{ for each $v\in \mathcal{V}$} & \quad \text{[the marginal of $f$ on $\mathcal{V}$ is $g$]}\\
& (3) \quad \int_{\mathcal{V}} f(v,1) u(v) dv \geq 0 \\
& (4) \quad \int_{\mathcal{V}} f(v,0) u(v) dv \leq 0 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Consider this other program: find a family of conditional mass functions  $h(\cdot| v):  \mathcal{Y}\rightarrow [0,1]$ for each $v\in \mathcal{V}$  such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (5) \quad \int_{\mathcal{V}} h(y|v)   g(v)dv=p(y)\quad && \text{ for each $y\in \mathcal{Y}$} \\
& (6) \quad  h(1|v)  g(v)+h(0|v)  g(v)=g(v)\quad  && \text{ for each $v\in \mathcal{V}$} & \quad \text{[seems trivially satisfied]} \\
& (7) \quad \int_{\mathcal{V}} h(1|v)  g(v) u(v) dv \geq 0 \\
& (8) \quad \int_{\mathcal{V}} h(0|v)  g(v) u(v) dv \leq 0 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

**Question:** (a) Is it correct that (1)-(4) have a solution with respect to $f$ if and only if (5)-(8) have a solution with respect to $\{h(\cdot|v)\}_{v\in \mathcal{V}}$? (b) Further, is (6) trivially satisfied?

Comment: Conditional probabilities are defined in terms of joint probabilities.  Joint probabilities can be fully reconstructed from the conditional probabilities--again, apply the definitions.  The details of your question would therefore seem irrelevant.  What you might mean by "less [fewer] constraints" is unclear, given that many of these constraints could be redundant.

Comment: Thanks. Therefore, the answer to my questions (a) and (b) is YES?